# Total of particular files size in a directory

Tags: files

How do we calculate the total size of some mentioned files in a directory.

Explained : I have a total of 5000 files in a directory. i need to find out only total size of some 1000 files.

Actually these 1000 files were to be deleted but before deleting in need to calculate the total sizes of these files.

I have names and path of these files in a text file. These files are in form of pdf, flv, pptx etc. like:

```
/digi_en-gb/var/www/html/content/Collaborative_Games/multiplication/SB/08_Multip‌​lication Maze SB_Done.doc 
/digi_en-gb/var/www/html/content/Project_Ideas/178401/178401_chart_food_secu.pdf 
/digi_en-gb/var/www/html/content/LessonPlan_Master/100079/AC1030T.pptx
```

Can some help me with a script or command to achieve this.

Comment: i have the list of files to be deleted. i need to know the total size of files before deleting it. So i need to make a script which will read from the text file and give out total size of those files.

Comment: If no one else did it by tonight, I will post an answer late today. I have the feeling however someone else will have by then :).

Comment: @Rshrth what particular files? (by extension or by any regex?) How do you want to delete that files(?) according to what pattern? please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/579580/edit) the question and add additional details. thanks

Comment: i have to files to be deleted in a text file (path and file names). But before deleting i need to find out their total size. Jacob need help here. I am using a script to delete these files.

Comment: You didn't tell me how do you determine those 1000 files to be delete? something deleting 1000 .pdf files or combination of .pdf and .flv files? or do you want to delete 1000 files randomly?

Comment: i have a created a script file in which i have put all those file name with rm -rf command.

Comment: Can you give an example, please?

Comment: Wait, *what* is exactly in the lines of the file? I assumed it had lines with paths to the files. Does it also include the remove *command* already? Please post back what is in the lines.

Comment: As of now i have the path in that file
examples 
/digi_en-gb/var/www/html/content/Collaborative_Games/multiplication/SB/08_Multiplication Maze SB_Done.doc
/digi_en-gb/var/www/html/content/Project_Ideas/178401/178401_chart_food_secu.pdf
/digi_en-gb/var/www/html/content/LessonPlan_Master/100079/AC1030T.pptx

Comment: Looking at your directories, I edited my answer. No offence, but it would be more productive if your communication was a bit more prompt. Also, be aware people are only notified of your comments if you ping them (@someone).

Answer (score 3):

If you had a *NUL terminated* list of files, then you could use the `--files0-from=` option of `du`. From `man du`:

```
   --files0-from=F
          summarize disk usage of the NUL-terminated file names  specified
          in file F; If F is - then read names from standard input
```

You could convert a newline-separated list to a NUL-separated list using `tr` e.g.

```
tr '\n' '\0' < filelist > filelist0
```

Then

```
du -sch --files0-from=filelist0
```

If you want to see *only* the total, then pipe the result through `tail`

```
du -sch --files0-from=filelist0 | tail -n 1
```

To avoid generating the extra file, you could do something like this instead

```
tr '\n' '\0' < filelist | du -sch --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Or, something like `find -name \*pdf -print0 | du -sch --files0-from=-`.

Answer (score 1):

I could not test it thouroughly yet, since I a not at home right now, but a small test makes me believe the script below should work.

It is an edited version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/574694/72216).

#### How to use

- Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `calculate_size.py`.
- open a terminal window, type the following command:

  ```
    python3 /path/to/calculate_size.py </path/to/your/textfile/with/a/filelist>
  ```
- *Note* if you need `sudo` privileges in the directories wher the files arte store, run the script with `sudo`:

  ```
     sudo python3 /path/to/calculate_size.py </path/to/your/textfile/with/a/filelist>
  ```

It shows an output like:

[image]

Your list should have one path to a file per line, no blank lines (else it would raise an error).

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys

f_list = sys.argv[1]
get = lambda x: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", x]).decode("utf-8")

with open(f_list) as src:
    files = [f.strip() for f in src.readlines()]

total_size = []
for f in files:
    size = get('du -hk "'+f+'"').split()[0]; total_size.append(int(size))
    print(f.strip('"')+"\t", size+" k")
print("-"*30, "\nnumber of files: "+str(len(total_size)), "\ntotal size: "+str(sum(total_size))+" k")
try:
    print("average size: "+str(int(sum(total_size)/len(total_size)))+" k\n\n")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass

proceed = input("Should I delete the listed files? \n(press return to proceed, x + return to cancel): ")
if proceed == "":
    for file in files:
        os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have saved files PATH like following format in `list`  file:

```
/path/to/filename0.pdf
/path/to/filename1.pdf
/path/to/filename0.flv
/path/to/filename0.pptx
...
```

And try below command which calls the `du -h` shell command from within `awk` for each line(`$0`) of the `list` file:

```bsh
awk '/.*pdf|.*flv$/{ system("du -h \"" $0 "\"") }' /path/to/list
13.2M   /path/to/filename0.pdf
5.3M    /path/to/filename1.pdf
50.18M  /path/to/filename0.flv
```

As you can see this will show you the size of each .pdf and .flv files in per line.

Now, if you want to calculate the sum of all file sizes use `awk`as follows:

```bsh
awk '/.*pdf|.*flv$/{ system("du -h \"" $0 "\"") }' /path/to/list | awk '{ SUM += $1} END{ print "Total "SUM" MB" }'
Total 68.68 MB
```

---

In addition you can use `rm` command within `awk` as tha same as `du` command to prompting the matched file **including its size in left** and hit `Y/N` to deleting the selected file. see in steps:

```bsh
$ ls path/to/
filename0.flv  filename0.pdf  filename1.pdf  filename.pptx  list

$ awk '/.*pdf$|.*flv$/{ system("du -h \"" $0 "\"" ";rm -i \"" $0 "\"")}' path/to/list
13.2M   /home/user/path/to/filename0.pdf
rm: remove regular file ‘/home/user/path/to/filename0.pdf’? y
5.3M    /home/user/path/to/filename1.pdf
rm: remove regular file ‘/home/user/path/to/filename1.pdf’? y
50.18M  /home/user/path/to/filename0.flv
rm: remove regular file ‘/home/user/path/to/filename0.flv’? y

$ ls path/to/
filename.pptx  list
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `find` and `du` in a terminal (bash ok)?

For example, to find all .pdf files, and display could use:

```
find /folder/path -iname *.pdf -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -c --block-size=human-readable
```

Or use whatever pattern you want in place of `*.pdf`

Or for single byte sizes, use the `du` option `--block-size=1`

The above shows the disk space used by the files, to show the "apparent size" (what `ls` usually shows) use the `du` option `--apparent-size`

Or, show only the grand total (`du -s`) and combine some options to show apparent file size in 1 bytes:

```
find /folder/path -iname *.pdf -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -bs
```

Want to cut off the path info & show only the bytes? Add `| cut -f 1`

See the `man` or `info` pages for `find`, `xargs`, and `du` for more info.

---

After question was edited to add the files are in a text file, can still use `xargs` along with it's option:

```
--arg-file=file
-a file
          Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this
          option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are  run.   Other‐
          wise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.
```

So:

```
xargs --arg-file=file du -bs
```

Comment: Hey Xen.. i hav 1000 files of all types of extensions in it.. I need to find out total size of all these files.

Comment: I was under the impression they were random files throughout the directories... this is easier then, cut off the `find` and `xargs`, and just use `du`

Comment: @Rshrth I've updated the answer with a "read from file" option. If the answer is at all helpful, or the best one, please give it an upvote &/or select/check-mark (noticed that only 3 of your 13 questions have selected/check-marked answers, it's more helpful to others if you select correct answers)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a specific list of files to be deleted and there's no restrictions in modeling the solution it's pretty straight forward (bash):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ];
then
    echo "Usage $0 filename";
    exit 1;
fi

totalsize=0;

while read filename
do
    filesize=`du $filename -b | awk '{print $1}'`
    totalsize=$(($totalsize + $filesize))
done < $1

echo "Total usage $totalsize bytes"
```

The `filesize` variable uses `du` to get the file's size in bytes. The output would be something like:

```
15 file.txt
```

whereas we would need only the `15` from that output, to parse I use awk, which print the first line (the delimiters are spaces)

Additionally if you want to delete the file too, just add `rm $filename` at the in the while cycle

Comment: this is not working

Comment: I've tested it on three different bash versions, it works eitherway. There might be a misunderstanding of the problem. Can you clarify what did not working when trying to execute the script?

Comment: i have a script which is giving me all file and folder size output. Let me know who can i sum up those file sizes to get total size(to be deleted). sorry for the delay
script 
#!/bin/sh
while read tmpTxt;
do
        fileSize=`find $tmpTxt -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{ print $5}'`
        echo $fileSize
done < /tmp/Retired_Objects_List.txt
Retired_object_list.txt (file containing the path to the files)